# unable to Connect with MsSql database in node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, connection

I am not able to connect with mssql server and i am getting error when executing the coding..

```js
exports.dbConfig = {
    // user: "sa",
    // password: "sa",
    // //server: "DESKTOP-QHBGOMQ",
    // server: '127.0.0.1',
    // //server: "localhost",
    // database: "ArduinoDataLogger",
    // port: 1433,
    //
    // connectionString: "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=#{server}\\sql;Database=#{database};Uid=#{user};Pwd=#{password};"
    userName: 'sa',
    password: 'sa',
    server: 'DESKTOP-QHBGOMQ',
    database: 'ArduinoDataLogger',
    port: 1443,
    debug: true,
    driver: 'tedious',
    options: {
        port: 1443,
        encrypt: false,
        database: 'ArduinoDataLogger',
        useColumnNames: false,
        debug: {
            packet: true,
            data: true,
            payload: true,
            token: true,
            log: true
        }
    }

};
```

The error i am getting it is:

```js
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-QHBGOMQ:1443 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at Connection.tedious.once.err (C:\Users\JanaVithu\Desktop\NewProject\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:237:17)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\JanaVithu\Desktop\NewProject\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1016:14)
    at C:\Users\JanaVithu\Desktop\NewProject\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:861:25
    at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\JanaVithu\Desktop\NewProject\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:154:9)
    at Socket.onError (C:\Users\JanaVithu\Desktop\NewProject\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:170:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError:
```

I have enabled tcp/ip and all my mssql server are running (automatic). 
i even changed the tcp/ip dynamic = 0..
i really have no idea how to fix it and i have tried all the possible solutions which was suggested by experts (forums)..

Thank you.
it would be great if anyone could suggest/help me to sort it out this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Use these settings, worked for me.

```
const config = {
  user: {user},
  password: {password},
  dialect: "mssql",
  server: {server},
  port:1435,
  database: {database},
  debug: true,  
  dialectOptions: {
    instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'
  }
};
sql.connect(config,function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("SQL DATABASE CONNECTED");  
});
```

**EDIT**

```
exports.dbConfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'sa',
    dialect: "mssql",
    server: 'DESKTOP-QHBGOMQ',
    database: 'ArduinoDataLogger',
    port: 1443, // check the port once again
    debug: true,
    dialectOptions: {
      instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @AtishayJain, if you do not mind could you explain me bit more further ? do i have to create the create the variable for user ?

Comment: no need both are correct just that the parameters should be same as mine `{}` means variable for example `{user}`

Comment: i've edited the answer check the port again and copy the edited code

Comment: Thanks again @atishayJain, Now i am able to connect with database, but getting new errors, and have no idea where it's come from.. Thanks for your help again